# @Html.BeginCollectionItem with IValidatableObject and MemberName mismatch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dynamic, guid, ivalidatableobject, begincollectionitem

While using [@Html.BeginCollectionItem](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/) helper by Steven Sanderson I'm trying to validate the *collection items* on the server side using the [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) interface.

I want to prevent the user from selecting two equal items. So for example, given a list of idioms the user speaks, one can postback these values:

```
English
English
Spanish
```

The `Validate` implementation looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    foreach(var idiom in Idioms)
    {
        if(Idioms.Any(i => i != idiom && i.Idiom == idiom.Idiom))
        {
            yield return new ValidationResult("Idiom already selected", new string[] { "Idiom" });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that the `MemberName` ("Idiom") passed to the `ValidationResult` is different from the `MemberName` present in the `ModelState` dictionary since the helper by Steven uses `Guid`'s and looks like this:

```
[42] = {[Idioms[83c2c6db-0157-42f3-bf3f-f7c9e6bc0a37].Idiom, System.Web.Mvc.ModelState]}
```

as you can see `Idiom != [Idioms[83c2c6db-0157-42f3-bf3f-f7c9e6bc0a37].Idiom`.

In the best case I'd have to have a way of passing for example `[Idioms[83c2c6db-0157-42f3-bf3f-f7c9e6bc0a37].Idiom` as the `MemberName` but I don't know how to get this info from the `validationContext` or even if that's possible at all. This has to be dynamic anyways.

Do you know about any way to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of Googling I found the right way of doing what I want:

[Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC 3](http://www.esenciadev.com/2011/02/model-validation-in-asp-net-mvc3-2/)

To validate (ie. find duplicate entries) in a collection/list property in your `ViewModel` you must add a

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Idioms)
```

for the property in your `View` and compose the `errorMessage` inside the `Validate` method. Finally assign the message to the correct property name, that is, `Idioms` in my case.

```
public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
{
    var grouping = Idioms.GroupBy(ui => ui.Idiom);

    var duplicates = grouping.Where(group => group.Count() > 1);

    if(duplicates.Any())
    {
        string message = string.Empty;

        foreach(var duplicate in duplicates)
        {
             message += string.Format("{0} was selected {1} times", duplicate.Key, duplicate.Count());
        }

        yield return new ValidationResult(message, new[] { "Idioms" });
    }
}
```

**BONUS**

If you want to display each duplicate group in `separate lines` (adding line breaks `<br>`), do this:

Replace `{0} was selected {1} times` with `{0} was selected {1} times<br>`

and then on the `View` side do this:

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Html.ValidationMessageFor(u => u.Idioms).ToHtmlString()))
```

Output will be:

```
French was selected 2 times
English was selected 3 times
```